# Shadows large scene threeJS

Tags: three.js, shadows

I have a large terrain scene with many objects that cast shadows on the terrain. It seems I need multiple light sources to achieve good shadow resolution.

I will probably need to edit the source code to make a particular light affect one object in the scene only so that it only casts shadows from that one light.

How do I edit the shadows SRC in THREE.JS to acheive this?